# Passthrough Touch Event

Tags: ios, uiview

What's the best way to passthrough a touch event to all subviews?

ViewController -> view -> (subview1, subview2)

I would like subview1 & subview2 to both respond to the touch event.

Answer (score 1):

Set the tags on the subviews equal to noticable tags. Then do a tree search through the views looking for those tags. Unfortunately there is not really a nice way to do this without subclassing. If you were willing to subclass then you would subclass view and then upon touch throw a NSNotification that all other views of that same subclass would listen for.

Answer (score 1):

In the parent's touch handler, you can iterate over the subviews of that view and call the same handler:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
       [subview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
       [subview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
   }
}
```

Or if you needed to identify specific subviews, you could assign integer Tags to the subviews to identify them later:

```
- (void)loadView {
   UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)];
   view1.tag = 100;
   [self.view addSubview:view1];

   UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
   view2.tag = 200;
   [self.view addSubview:view2];

}
```

Then later in the ViewController method invoked by the touch event

```
- (void)touchEventResponder {
   UIView *view1 = [self.view viewWithTag:100];
   // Do work with view1
   UIView *view2 = [self.view viewWithTag:200];
   // Do work with view2
}
```

Comment: is there a way to just pass the touch events through and let their default handlers deal with them? For example, I have a swipe gesture recognizer that dismisses an overlay and I want the scroll view underneath to receive the scroll touch events at the same time.

Comment: @nmock See my updated answer (at least the first code sample) . . . that should pass touch event information through a parent to the subview.  Note, though, that this will pass touch events to all subviews whenever the parent is touched, even if the subview doesn't cover the portion of the parent that was touched by the user.

Comment: I tried doing this but it still didn't work...I have a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to a view on "subview1" but it still doesn't want to respond to touch events. I subclassed UIView for the view overlay and pass all touch events to subviews, but still doesn't work. I can get it to work by calling bringSubviewToFront on the view underneath and it respond to touches, but then it will appear in front. Any ideas? I stumbled upon a project (https://github.com/spoletto/SquareQuote) that does the overlay and the views underneath respond, but I can't figure out how they did it.